# Synaptic founds version from repositories of newer distro

Tags: 18.04, synaptic

i don't know if this was asked before. After a quick search i did'nt find anything like this.

So, after a `do-release-upgrade` from 16.04 to 18.04 my sources probably somehow got messy, i don't know. The problem arrised when i tried to install wine and `apt` refused to install due to missing dependencies. So i started digging around to install what was needed.

I identified that first dependency was `libldap-2.4-2:i386`, so i tried to install it. But guess what, dependency fail. And then `libgnutls30:i386` and so. So i started digging [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/libgnutls30) to see what's going on.

I can see that the official repos has `libgnutls30:i386 (3.5.18-1ubuntu1.1)`. So far so good. Now i fire up `synaptic package manager` to see what version i have. Apparently my latest version is `3.6.5-2ubuntu1` which is not right i guess but on the parentheses it says bionic. The solution is probably to force the version i want but i would take a wild guess and say that the rest of dependencies would need that too.

Below are some pictures of synaptic with versions available:
[3.6.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDQfW.png),
[3.5.18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY2bO.png)

What is a probable source of this and why synaptic shows that version as `bionic` when it is in fact `disco` distribution? As for the install i guess of wine, i guess i will have to make it manually like i ll do for this.

Thanks in advance, if you need any more info please ask for it, i didn't mean to leave it behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching on how to see which source provides which packages and versions, i ended up with `apt-cache policy [offendingpackage]`.

Somehow a repository i was using for theming, provided core ubuntu packages but updated versions for this particular distribution (bionic). All i had to do was `purge` this repository along with the packages it provided and fall back to packages provided by ubuntu official repositories.

This was easily done with the package `y-ppa-manager`: [site here](https://itsfoss.com/y-ppa-manager/).

Purging the offending repositories and falling back to packages in official repository, fixed all the dependencies and wine could install (painlessly).